# Breeze.Sharp with non web-api/wcf data services

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

We are using EasyNetQ(RabbitMQ) with a data layer that uses EF6.1 
We are developing a WPF client that will request data via the Message Bus.  We would love to be able to use Breeze.Sharp to manage the data on the client but the only DataServices that are currently available are for WebApi/web(HttpClient) services.

Is it possible to introduce an interface so that we can provide a custom DataService that will communicate with the EasyNetQ message bus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, the breeze.sharp product is intended to be able to talk to all of the same  data services that our breeze.js product does.

Take a look at the breeze.dataService.mongo adapter ( part of the breeze.js product).  It is used to talk to a mongoDB database running on Node with Express. ( i.e. no WebApi and actually no .NET on the server at all. )

That said, we have not yet built other adapters for the breeze.sharp product, although we plan to, as well as provide documentation on how to do this yourself.  No timeframes yet unfortunately, we have a lot on our plate.

Another alternative to waiting, is to contact breeze@ideablade.com to build the adapter for you.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I had to move quite a lot of things around to accomplish this. I added some DI, and also moved the HttpClient code into the WebApi Adapter since it is really tightly coupled with the adapter type.  One issue I am having is that there are a lot of classes that are marked internal/protected.  I have changed some to public, reluctantly for now. I had to do this to create an Adapter externally to Breeze. I hope in the near term the Breeze.Sharp DataService can be updated to allow 3rd party Adapters to be created externally.